# If $h$ is continuously differentiable, is $\overline{\{h=0\}\cap\{h'\ne0\}}=\{h=0\}\cap\overline{\{h'\ne0\}}$?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, derivatives

Let $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable and $N:=\{h=0\}\cap\{h'\ne0\}$.

> Are we able to show that $\overline N=\{h=0\}\cap\overline{\{h'\ne0\}}$?

By general topology, we only know "$\subseteq$".

Comment: With $h(x)=x^2$, $N =\emptyset$, but $\overline{\{h’ \neq 0\}} \cap \{h=0\}=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x) = x^2$.  Then $\{h = 0\} = \{0\}$ and $\{h' \ne 0\} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.  Thus $N = \overline{N} = \emptyset$.  However, $\overline{\{h' \ne 0\}} = \mathbb{R}$, so $\{h = 0\} \cap \overline{\{h' \ne 0\}} = \{0\} \ne \overline{N}$.